# Is it possible to check value by regexp in Backbone Router?

Tags: backbone.js

For example I have:

```
(function (exports, $, _, CategoriesController) {
    "use strict"
    var App = exports.App;
    App.Routers = {},
    App.Routers.Index = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "category=:category": "category",
            "*actions"          : "defaultRoute"
        },
        page: function (pageNumber) {
            App.CategoriesFilter.setPage(pageNum);
        },
        defaultRoute: function () {
            alert('default');
        }
    });
}(window, jQuery, _));
```

But what if page number should be only integer? how to check it in the router? Is it possible? If not, - how to perform other action? Using `navigate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a link that might be what you're looking for:

> http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/12/regex-routing-with-backbone-js/